# Angular application with Java

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, jenkins

This is very basic question and i am new to this..Can anyone tell me the structure for `Angular js` with `Java` & `Maven`. I want to create application using `angular 1.x` with `Java` using `maven` and also i want to use jersey(rest api) to make `microservice` call to pull data.How would be the structure for this application?

Note: I want to use grunt or gulp for development purpose and even integrate with jenkins jobs

Comment: You can check jhipster.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same one as any Maven web application. Maven doesn't care about what JS framework you use, if any. JS files are static files that must be served by the app, just like any other static file.

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html for the structure of a war project.

Comment: Thanks for your response..do you have any sample application which contains the features

Comment: No, I don't have such a thing.